# Convertir XML a objeto en Java

Tags: java, xml, restful

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual necesito convertir un xml que obtengo desde un RestFul y convertirlo a un objeto en Java y no se como hacerlo, alguien que me ayude.

Comment: Talvez encuentres algo que te sirva [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896801/convert-xml-string-to-java-object) o [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779755/how-do-i-convert-xml-into-a-java-value-object), para darte una idea de tu desarrollo

Comment: Te sugerimos agregar información, que has tratado o investigado, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JAXB es el estándar de Java ( [JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) ) para convertir objetos a / desde XML. Lo siguiente debería ayudar:

**Descomponer desde una cadena**

Tendrá que envuelva el `String` de una instancia de StringReaderantes de que sus impl JAXB puede deserializar ella.

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Response response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
```

**Diferentes nombres de campo y XML**

Puede usar la `@XmlElement` anotación para especificar cuál quiere que sea el nombre del elemento. Por defecto, JAXB analiza las propiedades. Si desea basar las asignaciones en los campos, debe configurarlas `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

```
@XmlElement(name="count")
private int size;
```

**Espacios de nombres**

Las anotaciones `@XmlRootElementy @XmlElement` también le permiten especificar la calificación del espacio de nombres donde sea necesario.

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.example.com")
public class Response {
}
```

**En Conclusion**

JAXB crea objetos java a partir de archivos XML. Primero deberá generar clases Java utilizando el generador de código de jaxb que toma XSD como entrada y luego serializar / deserializar estos archivos xml de manera adecuada.

**Referencias**

> http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
>   http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html
>   http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Bueno en este caso tal vez tendrias que mencionar las referencias: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html,  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html,  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html XDXD

Comment: Cierto se me paso lo lamento.

Comment: genial me ayudo mucho!!!